# Updating state in reducer using variables

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I'm build a simple app that expands and collapses sections of content based on their state. Basically, if collapse = false, add a class and if it's true, add a different class.

I'm using Next.js with Redux and running into an issue. I'd like to update the state based on an argument the action is passed. It's not updating the state and I'm not sure why or what the better alternative would be. Any clarification would be great!

```
// DEFAULT STATE    
const defaultState = {
  membership: 'none',
  sectionMembership: {
    id: 1,
    currentName: 'Membership',
    nextName: 'General',
    collapse: false
  },
  sectionGeneral: {
    id: 2,
    prevName: 'Membership',
    currentName: 'General',
    nextName: 'Royalties',
    collapse: true
  }
}

// ACTION TYPES
export const actionTypes = {
  SET_MEMBERSHIP: 'SET_MEMBERSHIP',
  MOVE_FORWARDS: 'MOVE_FORWARDS',
  MOVE_BACKWARDS: 'MOVE_BACKWARDS'
}

// ACTION
export const moveForwards = (currentSection) => dispatch => {
  return dispatch({ type: actionTypes.MOVE_FORWARDS, currentSection })
}

// REDUCERS
export const reducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case actionTypes.SET_MEMBERSHIP:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          membership: action.membershipType
        })
      case actionTypes.MOVE_FORWARDS:
        const currentId = action.currentSection.id
        const currentName = "section" + action.currentSection.currentName    
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          currentName: {
            id: currentId,
            collapse: true
          }
        })
    default: return state
  }
}
```

The currentName variable is causing an issue for the state to not update. I want to be able to dynamically change each sections state, which is why I thought I'd be able have a variable and update state like this.

It seems you can't use a variable for the key in the key/value pair. Why is this? What's an alternative to dynamically updating state?

Comment: Use bracket around the `currentName` in your `Object.assign`. Like: `[currentName]`. See `Computed property names` in [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because JavaScript understands that you want to create a key named `currentName` not a key with the value of the variable `currentName`. In order to do what you want, you have to wrap `currentName` in brackets:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
          [currentName]: {
            id: currentId,
            collapse: true
          }
        })
```

So it will understand that the key will be whatever `currentName` is.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks! Is it possible to pass in the rest of the properties in state that weren't changed? (e.g. nextName, currentName) My components are receiving the update state, but only what was changed and not the entire object.

Comment: Yes, you just have to do `[currentName]: {
            id: currentId,
            collapse: true,
            ...this.state[currentName]
          }` if you are using ES6. See more on this [Wes Bos's article](http://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/)

Comment: Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

It also right:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
  [currentName]: Object.assign({}, state[currentName], {
    id: currentId,
    collapse: true
  })
})
```