# Dynamic cache naming in Redux based on some value from action payload - React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I know it is easiy to create a cache in a redux reducer like this:

```
switch (action.type){
  case CACHE_DATA:
      return {...state, cachedData: action.payload};
}
```

Where **CACHE_DATA** is the name of my action. And **cachedData** is the hardcoded name of a redux cache.

But I was wondering if it was possible to name the cache dynamically using some value from action payload instead of using a hard-coded name like "cachedData"?

May be something like this:

```
switch (action.type){
    case CACHE_DATA:
    {
        var cacheName = "cachedData_" + action.payload.SOME_ID; 
        return {...state, cacheName : action.payload};
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after posting this I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47964203/1680793

So it can be done like this:

```
switch (action.type){
    case CACHE_DATA:
    {
        var cacheName = "cachedData_" + action.payload.SOME_ID; 
        return {...state, [cacheName] : action.payload};
    }
}
```

Easy!